# Syntax error in VBA due to region difference

Tags: vba, syntax

we're using excel macro for development work and mainly US team is developed. Whenever they deploy new macro it has some syntax issue.
I just copied file from server and paste my laptop but it shows syntax error as below, I requested to confirm again from colleague, there is no issue.
(Sorry I could not share whole code)

: Syntax Error code, When I got error, code show like below.

```
modyear = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(modyear, "?, "")
```

--> the code missed quotation mark at behind of question mark, so if I modified code with additional quotation market then it works well.

Does anyone know what's the reason to change character or way to find out root cause.
Thank you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194878.aspx The Substitue command is expecting a string and it looks as though the string was never closed as you indicated.

Answer (score 0):

[msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194878.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194878.aspx)

The "Substitute" expression is expecting a string and it looks as though the string was never closed as you indicated. So instead of using the above it should be written as follows:

```
modyear = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(modyear, "?", "")
[String With Text] = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute([String With Text], [Find This String], [Replace Found String With This])
```